# UserControl not in assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

So I have an WPF UserControl and I am trying to "instantiate"/call one in MenuVsHorsLigne.XAML

The usercontrol was created by doing a right click on **UserInterface** and *Adding a new element* on which I selected UserControl in WPF. (IE  MapDisplay.XAML)

Here is my project's skeleton :

**GamingClient**

- Folder|Assets
- Folder|Chat
- Folder|GameEngine
- Folder|Maps
- Folder|UserInterface

In **UserInterface**

- MenuVsHorsLigne.xaml
- MapDisplay.xaml

Here is my MapDisplay.xaml code :

```
<UserControl x:Class="GamingClient.UserInterface.MapDisplay"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Border BorderBrush="#a197ff" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5 5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image MaxHeight="64" Source="/GamingClient;component/Assets/next.png" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Image MaxHeight="64" Source="/GamingClient;component/Assets/prev.png" Grid.Column="0"/>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image  MaxHeight="215" MaxWidth="215" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0" Source="/Maps/1.jpg"/>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ComboBox Name="comboBoxMapsName" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxWidth="200"  Margin="5 0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="White" Text="Description de la carte par l'auteur qui n'apporte aucune information pertinente aux yeux du joueur ou de son adversaire qui lui est aussi pourri que l'hôte."  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10 5 5 5" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my MenuVsHorsLigne.xaml ///Removed alot of stuff thats has no part in the problem

```
<Window x:Class="GamingClient.UserInterface.MenuVsHorsLigne"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MenuVsHorsLigne" Height="559"  MinHeight="350" Width="633" MinWidth="600"
        Closed="Window_Closed"
        IsVisibleChanged="Window_IsVisibleChanged"
        xmlns:custom="GamingClient.UserInterface">
    <Grid>
        <custom:MapDisplay Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column ="0"></custom:MapDisplay>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Problem is, VS2010 doesn't find MapDisplay in the XAML Namespace.... having followed various tutorial and tried to find similar issue... my code seems fine so I have no freaking idea on what is making MapDisplay "invisibile".

Here is the code .cs of MapDisplay.xaml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GamingClient.UserInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MapDisplay.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MapDisplay : UserControl
    {
        public MapDisplay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering... In your code-behind (.cs portion of the class), is it defined as public?

Comment: Its a public and partial - default settings (didnt touch the .cs at all)

Comment: Added code into the question. It really is bugging me out :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this to register namespace

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:GamingClient.UserInterface"
```

Comment: Actually it worked in Vs 2013, but it does not in 2010